# add class if find sequence using prev()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

i have code like this

```
<section id="homepage-statistic"></section>

<div id="allcontentbg">
   <div id="allcontent">    
       <div id="pagecontent">
           <div class="main-box-eran"></div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

i want add class to first section named **home10** if find sequence like this

**#allcontentbg #allcontent #pagecontent .main-box-eran**

i try this

```
$('#allcontentbg').prev('#homepage-statistic').addClass('homepage-statistic-1')
```

and work but i want if find sequence like this **#allcontentbg #allcontent #pagecontent .main-box-eran**
not if find **#allcontentbg** only

thank you

Edited :

guys your code work but i have problem, when have div between this sequence **#allcontentbg #allcontent #pagecontent .main-box-eran** script work also and add class i want script work only if have **#allcontentbg #allcontent #pagecontent .main-box-eran** without any other div inside him par example if have **#allcontentbg #allcontent #pagecontent #publicpage .main-box-eran** i want script not work because added **#publicpage**

Comment: guys your code work but i have problem, when have div between this sequence **#allcontentbg #allcontent #pagecontent .main-box-eran** script work also and add class 

i want script work only if have  **#allcontentbg #allcontent #pagecontent .main-box-eran** without any other div inside him 
par example if have **#allcontentbg #allcontent #pagecontent #publicpage .main-box-eran** i want script not work because added #publicpage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check using `length` if the mentioned chain of divs exists or not and based on that, using `closest()`, you can add the needed class. And you can use `not()`, to check for not having a certain class or ID.

```
if($("#allcontentbg #allcontent #pagecontent .main-box-eran").length){
    $('#allcontentbg').prev().addClass('homepage-statistic-1');
}
```

Comment: its work but i have problem also if find #allcontentbg #allcontent #pagecontent #otherdiv .main-box-eran

script added class to section, i want only this length #allcontentbg #allcontent #pagecontent .main-box-eran but if added any other div inside this length i want  script do not add class

Comment: As I said, you can use `not()` or you can use `>` operator to traverse exactly the same chain of divs that you are defining. Example: `$("#allcontentbg > #allcontent > #pagecontent > .main-box-eran")`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just chain the IDs and class names in jQuery like this, and use closest to select the section

```
$('#allcontentbg #allcontent #pagecontent .main-box-eran').closest('section').addClass('homepage-statistic-1')
```

EDIT:

I didnt notice that section wasnt a parent. This should work though:

```
$('#allcontentbg #allcontent #pagecontent .main-box-eran').closest('#allcontentbg').prev().addClass('homepage-statistic-1');
```

EDIT2:

Here is the updated code I mentioned in the comment below

```
$('#allcontentbg > #allcontent > #pagecontent > .main-box-eran').closest('#allcontentbg').prev().addClass('h‌​omepage-statistic-1'‌​);
```

Comment: its work but i have problem also if find #allcontentbg #allcontent #pagecontent #otherdiv .main-box-eran script added class to section, i want only this length #allcontentbg #allcontent #pagecontent .main-box-eran but if added any other div inside this length i want script do not add class

Comment: If you don't want any other classes in between, you can use the > operator like this
`$('#allcontentbg > #allcontent > #pagecontent > .main-box-eran').closest('#allcontentbg').prev().addClass('homepage-statistic-1');`

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this. Its working well:

```
if($('#allcontentbg #allcontent #pagecontent .main-box-eran').length != 0) {
    $('#allcontentbg').closest('section').addClass('homepage-statistic-1');
}
```